# SwiftUI: Display JSON Data with Text() instead of List

Tags: json, api, swiftui, urlsession, jsondecoder

I have got a problem with displaying JSON data on a SwiftUI View. 
I tried several tutorials and read articles which are related to my problem, but nothing seems appropriate enough.

For example everyone displays JSON data from an API with a fancy list or pictures, but I only want to know **how you can simply display one word** on a view (without `List{}`).

I chose the PokeAPI to figure out how to display "*Hi Charmander*" with the `Text()` instruction.

**Example of a list (and without `ObservableObject` and `@Published`)**

I want to get rid of the List and use sth. `Text(resultsVar[0].name).onAppear(perform: loadData)` like instead

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct pokeRequest:Codable {
    var results: [Result]

}
struct Result:Codable {
    var name:String

}

struct ViewOne: View {

    @State var resultsVar = [Result]()

    var body: some View {

        VStack{
        //unfortunately this does not work:
            //Text(resultsVar[0].name).onAppear(perform: loadData)
        List(resultsVar, id: \.name) { item in
                   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                       Text("Hi \(item.name)")
                   }
            }
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
}
    func loadData(){

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=3&limit=3") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            if let data = data {
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(pokeRequest.self, from: data) {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.resultsVar = decodedResponse.results
                    }
                return
                }
            }
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ViewOne_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewOne()
    }
}
```

**Second try with a different approach (without `.onAppear()`)**
In this approach I tried with `class: Observable Object` and `@Published` but I also didn't come to my wished UI-output.

```swift
 import SwiftUI
 struct pokeRequest2:Codable {
     var results2: [pokeEach2]
 }

 struct pokeEach2:Codable {
     var name2:String
 }


 class Webservice:ObservableObject {
     @Published var pokeInfo: [pokeRequest2] = [pokeRequest2]()

     func decodepokemon() {

         let session = URLSession.shared
         let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=3&limit=3")!
         let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

             if error != nil || data == nil {
                 print("Client error!")
                 return
             }

             guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                 print("Server error!")
                 return
             }

             guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
                 print("Wrong MIME type!")
                 return
             }

             do {
                 let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(pokeRequest2.self, from: data!)

                 print(self.pokeInfo[0].results2[0].name2)

                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.pokeInfo = [response]
                    }

             }  catch {
                 print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
             }
         }.resume()
     }

     init() {
         decodepokemon()
     }
 }

 struct ViewTwo: View {
     @ObservedObject var webservice: Webservice = Webservice()

      var body: some View {

              Text("please help")
        //Does also not work: Text(self.webservice.pokeInfo2[0].results2[0].name2)//.onAppear()
        //Since a few minutes somehow the debug area prints "JSON error: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing." instead of "charmander"
      }
 }
 struct ViewTwo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
     static var previews: some View {
         ViewTwo()
     }
 }
```

I tried several tutorials and read articles which are related to my problem, but nothing seems appropriate enough. 
**I would highly appreciate any help :-) 
Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert (started using Swift less than three days ago) but I think I might have what you are looking for. This enables you to call a simple REST API that contains only a simple dictionary (in my case the dictionary contains "Differential": 5.22) and then display that number as text when a button is pressed. Hope the following is helpful!

```
struct DifferentialData: Decodable {
var Differential: Double
}

struct ContentView: View {

@State var data = DifferentialData(Differential: 0.00)

func getData() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "Enter your URL here")
    else { return } //Invalid URL
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        let differentials = try!       JSONDecoder().decode(DifferentialData.self, from: data!)
        print(differentials)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.data = differentials
        }
    }
    .resume()
}

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        Text("\(data.Differential)")
        Button("Refresh data") {self.getData()}
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question but in SwiftUI text can be displayed as follows:

```
Text("Hi" + item.name)
```

But as I say I'm not sure if that's the question.

Comment: thank you for your answers. but the solution shouldn't deal with `item` anymore, because I want to get rid of the List{} and the loop in it. My view should only contain sth. like: `Text(resultsVar[0].name).onAppear(perform: loadData)` which should display "Charmander"

Answer (score 0):

As you will dynamically change the list items, you have to use .id() modifier. And in order to use .id(), the result must conforms to `Hashable`. The following code can help you solve the problem.

```
struct Result:Codable, Hashable {
var name:String

}

struct ViewOne: View {

@State var resultsVar = [Result]() // [Result(name: "firsy"),Result(name: "second"), ]//[Result]()

  var body: some View {

    VStack{
    Spacer()
    //unfortunately this does not work:
        //Text(resultsVar[0].name).onAppear(perform: loadData)
    List(resultsVar, id: \.name) { item in
               VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                   Text("Hi \(item.name)")
               }
        }.id(resultsVar)

}.onAppear(perform: loadData)
```